# How to merge MP4 video without audio with MP3 file using CLI tools, considering offset

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a challenge I'm hoping to solve with your expertise. I possess an MP4 video file that lacks audio, and a separate MP3 audio file that I wish to synchronize and merge with the video. The complexity is that the audio and video are not currently in sync. Through manual analysis, I've determined that a specific moment in the audio file (2:13:29) corresponds to a particular moment in the video (2:09:17). I would like to merge the files in the way that the initial 4 minutes and 12 seconds of the video will remain black, only with audio.

Could anyone guide me through the process of merging these two files into a single video file with synchronized audio on Ubuntu? Any command-line utilities that could facilitate this task would be greatly appreciated.

I tried:

```
ffmpeg -i only_video.mp4 -itsoffset 252 -i only_audio.mp3 -c:v copy -c:a aac final_video_with_audio.mp4
```

But I get no first 252 seconds of only audio (with a blank screen) unfortunately...

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I'd suggest tackling this:

1. First, create a silent video lasting 252 seconds.
2. Then, re-encode your existing video file to match the format of the silent video.
3. Merge the two videos to ensure the video file's duration matches that of the audio file.
4. Add the audio track onto the merged video file.

You'll need **ffmpeg**, which you seem to already have, and **mkvtoolnix**, which can be installed with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install mkvtoolnix
```

To create the silent video:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=1280x720:r=30:d=252 -f lavfi -i anullsrc=r=44100:cl=stereo -c:v libx264 -t 252 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -b:a 128k -strict experimental 'silent_video.mp4'
```

To re-encode the main video file in the same format as the silent video (it can take quite some time if you have a big video file):

```
ffmpeg -i 'only_video.mp4' -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 128k 'only_video_converted.mp4'
```

To merge the two silent video files into one (that's why we needed to install **mkvtoolnix**: **mkvmerge** is a very easy to use video merge tool):

```
mkvmerge -o 'combined_video.mkv' 'silent_video.mp4' + 'only_video_converted.mp4'
```

To add the audio track onto the video file:

```
ffmpeg -i 'combined_video.mkv' -i 'only_audio.mp3' -c copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 'final_video_with_audio.mkv'
```

Your video with synchronized audio and the first 252 seconds of audio only is ready!

*In my test with a 33-second video and a 49-second audio segment, the results were as expected. However, be aware that processing times may significantly increase with the size of the video file.*

Comment: Thanks, it works, but how I can convert it back to mp4?

Comment: Here you go: ffmpeg -i 'final_video_with_audio.mkv' -codec copy 'final_video_with_audio.mp4'